# Add GCC into Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, compile, c++, gcc

I want to make programs in Netbeans (C++ language), but Netbeans doesn't detect C++ libraries and compiler.

How can I add GCC into Netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at this, might be able to give you some guidance.

http://netbeans.org/community/releases/67/cpp-setup-instructions.html

Comment: the netbens website doesn`t open.

Comment: There was an issue with the website loading then, it should be fine now.